# findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make a filter that when the user mention users, I try to open this accounts that have `@` For Example, if there are `@Users` this mention convert to link like Twitter.

My Filter That raise this error `'findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string''`

```
 import re

from django import template
register = template.Library()
def open_account(text):
    def open_account(text):
      results = re.findall("(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,20})")
      for result in results:
        result = result[0]
      return text.replace(result, '<a target="_blank" style="color: blue;"')


url_target_blank = register.filter(open_account, is_safe = True)
```

Comment: remove the except clause and you may get a more informative error message

Comment: I updated me qustion without except and it raised `findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

Comment: on the line 
`results = re.findall("(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,20})")`
you need to specify a string to search
you may be thinking of 
`find_re = re.compile("(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,20})")`
in which case you can do 
`results = find_re.findall(some_string)`

Comment: What's usefel of some_string